# Proof: Sum of two independent gaussian vectors is a gaussian vector

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, vectors, stochastic-calculus

I want to show that the sum of two independent gaussian vectors is a gaussian vector.
We had, that a gaussian vector can be written as $X=A*Z+b$ where $A$ is a real matrix, $b$ is a real vector and $Z$ is a vector with standardnormal distributed components. 
So let $X$ and $Y$ be two n-dimensional gaussian vectors. So we can write them in the following way:

$X=A*Z+b,~Y=B*Z+c,~ A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{nxn},~ c,b \in \mathbb{R}^n,~ Z \in \mathbb{R}^n,~Z\sim N(0,I)$

Can I use the same $Z$ here?
Then the sum would be

$X+Y=(A+B)*Z+(b+c)$

and so it would be a gaussian vector. Is that correct or do I have to argue in a different way?

And later I have to find out the covariance matrix, can I argue that cov($x_i, y_j$)=0, because the vectors $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Thank you!
Susan

Comment: Do you really think that AZ+b and BZ+c are independent, in general?

Comment: No, you're right, so I have to use Z1 and Z2...but how can I show than, that the sum X+Y is a gaussian vector? For gaussian vectors every linear combination of the components is normally distributed...does that help?

Comment: which techniques are you allowed to use?